# PhpStorm Defining a directory root

Tags: apache, phpstorm

I would like to define a **DIRECTORY_ROOT** in PhpStorm, as I am used to in VSCode. My directory root configured in Apache server is the `dist/` folder.

My project structure:

```
- dist/               <-- Apache directory root (css, js, html, ...)
- src/                <-- Typescript / sass files
- server/             <-- PHP files
```

Now I have the file `I18n.php` under `server/Language/I18n.php`. Parallel to this the vocabularies `server/Language/enGB.php`, `server/Language/enUS.php` and so on.

```
- dist/          
- src/            
- server/    
    - Language/
        - I18n.php
        - enGB.php
        - enUS.php       
    - Controller/
    - Storage/
```

Now I just want to include `enUS.php` and `enGB.php` in `I18n.php` using `include_once`. Since my Apache defined directory root is the `dist/` directory, I have to import absolutely from this directory, not relatively from `I18n.php`.

Normally the import must then look like this:

```
include_once('../server/Language/enUS.php');
```

However, PhpStorm throws the following warning:
**Path '../server/Language/enUS.php' not found**

So far I tried to get this setting via Settings/Directories, but unfortunately it doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: If you are in the `I18n.php` file and want to include `enGB.php` (which is in the same folder) then why not simply use `'./enGB.php'` or a more complete/safe `__DIR__ . '/enGB.php'` ?

Comment: As for defining web server root (at leats from web resource point of view) -- mark  your `dist` as a **Resource Root** -- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-folders-within-a-content-root.html#2197ed6e

Comment: P.S. If you are using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, you can provide the path at `Settings/Preferences | PHP | Include Analysis` -- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/php.html#include-analysis

Comment: BTW, because `include` and alike is a _special language construct_, parentheses  `()` are not needed around the argument: this one is a preferred way: `include_once '../server/Language/enUS.php';`

Comment: './enGB.php' is not working. Where can I find preferences? Using 2022.1.1RC, cannot find it.

Comment: *""Where can I find preferences?"*. Really? `File | Settings` is for Windows & Linux. `PhpStorm | Preferences` is for Mac.

Comment: *"'./enGB.php' is not working."* The one with the `__DIR__` constant usage should work. If not sure -- `$a = __DIR__ . '/enGB.php';` and then see what path that `$a` will have.

Comment: Cannot test it yet, my composer completly shut down https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72220141/composer-autoload-php-inserts-unicode-characters

Comment: You can make a separate PHP file where you manually include your `server/Language/I18n.php` and do not use Composer's autoloader for this. P.S. No idea on your Composer issue. But I suggest you make a new project (with minimal code) and test your composer setup there: start with a few basic files, then add your libs etc. Maybe the issue is elsewhere. And try restarting your PC -- quite often it cures such "suddenly stopped working" glitches/issues.

Comment: `__DIR__ ` solution is working. Thanks!